# <form> element breaks the layout - snippet included

Tags: html, css, forms

adding an  element as outermost element to this snippet the layout  is getting slightly broken

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/google-style-login

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        ....
```

adding the form element

```
<form>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        ....


</form>
```

how to fix via css in order that the result doesnt change respect the original snippet?

Comment: Put the form tag inside the div with class row? It's also really hard to guess what your meaning of "breaks" is as we don't have any comparison

Comment: i can't move the markup because the form is placed in an asp.net masterpage. To see what i mean for "breaks" add <form> as parent to the sippet linked upon as see yourself the result (forgive me for my english)

Comment: There is already a form contained there, you cannot have a form inside a form

Comment: if possible add container class to form tag !

Comment: add snippet here on SO not on external website , especially where you need to login :)

Comment: ohhhh stupid me, i didn't see that. thanks!!!  an another OT bonus question: is this sentece correct in english: "the layout is getting slightly broken" is there another way to say that? :D

Answer (score -2):

i changed the inner `<form>` to `<div>` and the layout gone well
thanks everybody

Comment: then why you used `form` in the first place? :) i mean...logically to use `div`  is a first impulse